# Is interim Bayes Nash equilibrium equivalent to ex ante Bayes Nash equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Lemma 6.1 in [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-4-431-55645-9_6/fulltext.html) says, essentially, that the equilibrium based on ex-ante optimization is equivalent to the equilibrium on type-dependent optimization.

Does it mean that the interim Bayes Nash equilibrium is equivalent to ex ante Bayes Nashe equilibrium? If not, can you give an example or a reference?